# Prisma could not connect MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, prisma

```
Prisma needs to perform transactions, which requires your MongoDB server to be run as a replica set. https://pris.ly/d/mongodb-replica-set
at wn.handleRequestError (D:\Next JS\-udemy-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6730)
at wn.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\Next JS\-udemy-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6119)
at wn.request (D:\Next JS\-udemy-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5839)
at async l (D:\Next JS\-udemy-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:9763)
at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/register/route.ts:16:18)
at async D:\Next JS\-udemy-clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:61466 {
  code: 'P2031',
  clientVersion: '5.3.1',
  meta: {}
}
```

I am trying to connect MongoDB compass with `localhost:27017` with Prisma and when I try to use `axios.post` it shows up the above error. Also when I connect with MongoDB Atlas it gives out DNS resolution proto error even I had added the IP address to whitelist so can anyone figure out where is the problem or suggest alternatives in order to have Prisma connect with MongoDB?

Comment: Your database needs to be configured as a replica set. Add a `replSetName` and then `rs.initiate()` it, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#procedure). Connectivity issues with Atlas would be a different question (and you should check that your IP is in the access list). By the way, Compass is a GUI admin tool, not the database that you connect to

Comment: For the issue to connect Prisma with MongoDB is it the best to use the MongoDB Atlas instead of Compass?

Comment: Compass is not a thing that you use "instead of" Atlas. Compass is a GUI client tool that connects to a MongoDB cluster whether that cluster is in Atlas or elsewhere. The consideration about whether to use Atlas or not (self-manage) is also not related to Prisma or not. Prisma is a client library that can be used with MongoDB clusters both in Atlas and not

Comment: So any suggestions even I followed the documentation the prisma could not work with MongoDB?